# Sound intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, intensity

A policeman measuring motor vehicle noise is exactly 7.5m from the line of traffic on a straight road . The Sound Intensity Level ( SIL) reading shown on his meter is 86 dB. An isolated house faces the road and is exactly 30m from the line of traffic . What will be the SIL reading if he measure outside the house .

and the answer is 74dB
I really want to know why!!!
please help , thank you so much

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Leon99ard_ and welcome to Physics SE. As Vincent Thacker has commented it is not customary to ask homework and "check my work" questions here (it is not "forbidden" but it is not **the** most common thing to do).

Now, regarding your question, if you know how geometric sound attenuation works then it is quite straight forward to calculate the attenuation due to distance.

So, you know that for spherical propagation the intensity is spread on a sphere whose area is quadrupled for every doubling of distance (you can see that from the area of a sphere which is given from $S = 4 \pi r^{2}$, where if you double $r$, $S$ will be quadrupled). So, the intensity at the house will be calculated like

$$ SIL_{30m} = 86 dB + 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{4 \pi r_{1}^{2}}{4 \pi r_{2}^{2}} \right) \implies \\
\implies SIL_{30m} = 86 dB + 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{7.5^{2}}{30^{2}} \right) \implies \\
\implies SIL_{30m} = 86 dB + 10 \log_{10} \left( \left( \frac{7.5}{30}\right)^{2} \right) \implies \\
SIL_{30m} = 86 dB + 10 \cdot 2 \cdot \log_{10} \left(\frac{7.5}{30}\right) \implies \\ 
\implies SIL_{30m} = 86 dB + 20 \log_{10} \left(0.25\right) \implies \\
\implies SIL_{30m} \approx 86 dB + 20 \cdot \left(- 0.602 \right) \implies \\
\implies SIL_{30m} \approx 86 dB - 12 dB \implies \\
\implies SIL_{30m} \approx 74 dB$$

Now, of course, this is an approximation for a point source (which could be quite good for large distances). On the other hand, it is customary (for a good reason) to model traffic as a line source due to the fact that it is "comprised" of many moving sources and it seems to be closer to a line if you look at it.

So, in this case (assuming an infinitely long line) the attenuation would be $3 ~ dB$ per distance doubling. Since $30 ~ m$ is four times $7.5 ~ m$ you would get a value $2 \cdot \left( - 3 ~ dB \right) \approx -6 ~ dB$ (you get twice the $-3 ~ dB$ because you have doubled the distance twice in order to go from $7.5 ~ m$ to $30 ~ m$).

Hope this helps to clarify the concept.